# Magento 2 Knockout bind on ajax response

Tags: template, ajax, knockoutjs, magento2.4, knockout

I am going crazy with knockout on Magento 2, I am new to knockout and I cannot understand what I am doing wrong. I know there are some related questions posted there but each one is different from what I need. I checked all questions posted before, all links on google, still cannot understand why is not working.

I am trying to retrieve the shipping data on product page on Magento 2 and append them with foreach inside template.

That is what I have until now:

**calculate.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/storage',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko'
], function (
    $,
    $t,
    storage,
    utils,
    Component,
    ko
) {

    return Component.extend({

        defaults: {
            carrier: null
        },
        initialize: function (config) {
            var self = this;
            this._super();
            this.carrier = ko.observable();
            this.carrier_f(this.sku);
            return this;
        },
        carrier_f: function (sku) {
            var address;
            var postcode;
            var myViewModel;
            var carrier_view = {};

            var serviceUrlCreate, serviceUrl, payload;
            /**
             * Save  values .
             */
            serviceUrl = '/rest/V1/working_function/' + sku;
            payload = JSON.stringify({
                    address: {
                        'city': '',
                        'region_id': '569',
                        'country_id': 'US',
                        'postcode': '',
                    }
                }
            );
            storage.post(
                serviceUrl,
                payload
            ).done(function (response) {
                this.carrier = ko.observable();

                var carrier_view = {
                    'carrier': this.response
                };


                ko.cleanNode($('#shipping_results')[0]);
                ko.applyBindings(carrier_view, $('#shipping_results')[0]);

                console.log(response);

            }).fail(function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            });

        },

        checkShipping: function () {

            console.log(this.sku);
            
            this.carrier_f(this.sku);
        }
        
    });
    
});
```

form.phtml

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'shipping_estimate'">
    <ul id="shipping_results" data-bind="foreach: carrier">
        <li>
            <span data-bind="text: carrier_title"></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
    <button data-bind="click: checkShipping" class="btn-estimate">Check</button>

    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
                                       {
                                          "*": {
                                                  "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                                                         "components": {
                                                             "shipping_estimate": {
                                                                  "component": "Vendor_Name/js/calculate",
                                                                  "sku": "<?= $block->getProduct()->getSku(); ?>"
                                                              }
                                                         }
                                                   }
                                             }
                                        }                                  
    </script>
```

Ajax Response is like that:

[image]

So basically I need to get results on page load and also when click the Check Button (I will add some textbox after), but now there are not results inside, just empty response.

I tried everything, but still not found a solution, the only thing seems working is to change the scope to "anything-else", then the foreach is working, but the click event is not called.

If anyone has the patience to explain me what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You are close to a working solution I think. At a first glance I see that your button is not in scope of your scope binding. So the call to checkShipping will not be called.

I think the code becomes a bit hard to read when one has binding in the code like that. I would take a slightly different approach. Here are some example code (I kept your component imports):

app/code/StackExchange/Shipping/view/frontend/web/js/calculate.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/translate',
    'mage/storage',
    'mageUtils',
    'uiComponent',
    'ko'
], function (
    $,
    $t,
    storage,
    utils,
    Component,
    ko
) {
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            carrier: []
        },
        initObservable: function() {
            this._super().observe(['carrier']);

            return this;
        },
        checkShipping: function () {
            carriers = this.getCarriers();
            this.carrier(carriers);
        },
        getCarriers: function() {
            console.log(this.sku);
            return [
                {
                    carrier_title: 'Free Shipping',
                },
                {
                    carrier_title: 'Expensive shipping',
                }
            ];
        },
    });
});
```

app/code/StackExchange/Shipping/view/frontend/templates/shipping-estimate.phtml

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'shipping_estimate'">
    <div>
        <ul id="shipping_results" data-bind="foreach: carrier">
            <li>
                <span data-bind="text: carrier_title"></span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <button data-bind="click: checkShipping" class="btn-estimate">Check</button>
</div>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                "components": {
                    "shipping_estimate": {
                        "component": "StackExchange_Shipping/js/calculate",
                        "sku": "someSku"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

This renders a clickable button like this. That displays the carrier_title from the array when the button is clicked:

[image]

Feel free to ask if you have any questions.
Good luck!